# why argv in createProcess() is different from normal c++ program

Tags: c++, winapi

this is my code, and i found the first output is "thisProgram.exe" 
and the second output is "a".

why?

i read the doc in msdn, however i don't quite clear why the argv[0] can be "a", is there something different in windows when using createProcess. Could someone please tell me the difference from lpApplicationName and lpCommandline? thanks

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
cout << argv[0] << endl;

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

// Start the child process.
if (!CreateProcess("thisProgram.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
                   "a b c",        // Command line
                   NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                   NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                   FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                   0,              // No creation flags
                   NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                   NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
                   &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                   &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        ) {
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Close process and thread handles.
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: It is an obscure factoid about CreateProcess(), the argv[0] value in the program you start is set by the 1st argument.  So it is better to pass NULL and use the 2nd argument to specify both exe and arguments, that forces the OS to figure out argv[0].  ShellExecuteEx() is a bit more friendly.

Comment: @HansPassant: There's nothing *"obscure"* about passing arbitrary data to a new process. The **convention** to pass the executable image's path name as the first argument is so ubiquitous that it is often perceived as a strict rule. It isn't, and `CreateProcess` reflects that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateProcess` passes the second argument (the command line) to the new process as its command line. `CreateProcess` will not prepend the module name. If you want the application name to appear as `argv[0]` you must repeat the application name in the command line argument.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) says it like this:

> If both lpApplicationName and lpCommandLine are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line. The new process can use GetCommandLine to retrieve the entire command line. Console processes written in C can use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command line. Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.

It's generally simplest to pass `NULL` for the application name, and for the command line pass the application name and the arguments concatenated together.

Comment: thanks. I think the only usage of lpApplicationName is make process in which path havs " " in it run correctly. However, lpCommandLine also can do it (althought it is not recommanded). why this argument exist? and could you please tell me a example of using lpApplicationName, the example in documentation didn't use lpApplicationName either.

Comment: I don't know of such an example. I know that I always pass `NULL` for the application name.

Comment: @Charlie: `CreateProcess` allows you to pass an arbitrary command line to a new process. It is a **convention** to pass the path name to the executable image as the first command line argument, but there is no technical requirement to do so. If a process expects something else as its first 'command line parameter', `CreateProcess` allows you to do that.

Comment: Oh, I see, Thank you